# Angular custom component attribute setting

Tags: angular

(anyone is welcome to rephrase my question, I am not sure how to word it)

Say I created an Angular component, something like this:

```
<app-my-test></app-my-test>
```

How can I allow the user to set options on and off by just typing the option into the component, something like this:

```
<app-my-test booleanCheck></app-my-test>
```

Then in my .ts file, I would like `booleanCheck` to be true if they added it, and false if they didn't add it. Below is a blitz to play around with. The goal is to get the `console.log` to log `true` if `booleanCheck` was added, and `false` if it was not added.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xr3p84?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

I do NOT want this as an answer please:

```
<app-my-test booleanCheck="true"></app-my-test>
<app-my-test [booleanCheck]="true"></app-my-test>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `leverage` the `setter` of `@Input` which will be called if the `input` is available.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-test',
  templateUrl: './app.test.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.test.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  private _booleanCheck = false;

  @Input()
  set booleanCheck(param) {   // this is setter for booleanCheck input.
    this._booleanCheck = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    console.log(this._booleanCheck);
  }
}
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ubmg7

Comment: Thank you very much :) Would you mind just adding a little bit of information on what `set` does please? This is new to me so understanding it will help a lot.

Comment: Added sort comment.

Comment: But what does the `setter` do though?

Comment: Since the `setter` is decorated with `@Input.` So if the input `booleanCheck` is provided, it will call the `setter` instead of setting the `value` of `variable` directly.

Comment: Oh ok! So if someone does `[booleanCheck]="donkey"`, the booleanCheck will NOT be set to donkey, only the setter will be called?

Comment: It will be passed as argument  to ` set booleanCheck(param)`. It is up to you what you want to do with it. In your case we are not using at all.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to create a directive that will set the property for you in the host component (Note that the property may no longer be an `@Input`):

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fa3fzh?embed=1&file=src/app/test/app.test.html)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-test',
  templateUrl: './app.test.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.test.css' ]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  public booleanCheck: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    console.log(this.booleanCheck);
  }
}

@Directive({
   selector: '[booleanCheck]' 
})
export class BooleanCheck {
  constructor(@Host() @Self() @Optional() host: TestComponent) {
      host.booleanCheck = true;
  }
}
```

(For an even simpler solution, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53314169/142637))

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing the attribute to the custom component, it is not possible to add it like how you want. You are passing the input to the custom component and it should be like

```
<app-my-test [booleanCheck]="true"></app-my-test>
```

In your component it can be taken like

```
@Input() booleanCheck;
```

And if its true / false, you can enable / disable the logs.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your answer is exactly what I stated I do not want, so you are not really help man

Comment: In this case, there is no way to add the attribute to the custom component as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to check if the variable `booleanCheck` is undefined or not. This will `console.log(this.booleanCheck)` an empty string:

```
<app-my-test booleanCheck></app-my-test>
```

This will `console.log(this.booleanCheck)` undefined

```
<app-my-test></app-my-test>
```

So you can maybe use that to assign `false if undefined` and `true if it is an empty string`